# How to generate RSA key-pairs in Angular with pass phrase?

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption, cryptography, rsa

**Background**

My goal is to generate RSA key-pairs on frontend (Angular) with pass-phrase (Secret text) and public key should be sent to backend server (Node js in my case) which will help to encrypt data.

To generate RSA key-pairs on frontend I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptico-js
which is a decent package to generate key-pairs using pass phrase.

On backend server I used Node js Crypto module to encrypt data using public key.

Code to generate RSA key-pairs in Angular:

```
const PassPhrase = "My secret text"; 
const Bits = 1024; 
const RSAkeypairs = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);
const PublicKey = cryptico.publicKeyString(RSAkeypairs);
```

Code to Encrypt data (as Node js):

```
const publicKey =
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
    <MyPublicKey> +
    "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
  const data = "Hello temp content!";
  const buffer = Buffer.from(data);
  const encryptedText = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
  console.log(encryptedText.toString("base64"));
```

**Problem**

When I am using public key generated by **cryptico-js**, it throws below error:

```
Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
```

While if I use public key generated through other package, it works perfectly but they don't have **pass-phrase** during RSA key-pairs generation.

**Question**

Do we have any other package available for Angular which can accept pass-phrase (this is must due to business requirement) to generate RSA key-pairs or any other way around to fix error?

Comment: The problem is that `cryptico.publicKeyString()` is not returning a public in any standard format, it's just returning the raw modulus as a base64-encoded string. The public exponent is hard-coded to 3. Node crypto accepts RSA keys in PKCS1 or SPKI format. PKCS1 is slightly easier to produce by hand, being just a SEQUENCE { modulus INTEGER, publicExponent INTEGER}. The PEM wrapper for a PKCS1 RSA key starts out ""-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"

Comment: Everything else cryptico does is also unique to it. You may have a lot of work to get cryptico and Node crypto to interoperate.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk I stick with `cryptico` just because of **pass-phrase** and unable to find javascript library which can help me on this. How you came to know the public exponent is hard-coded to 3?

Comment: I looked at the source code on github.